# jQuery - How to get the data from txt file

Tags: jquery

If I have the following data in text.txt file, how to get these data and split it to array

txt

```
arr[0] =>There
arr[1] =>is
arr[2] =>no
arr[3] =>jQuery
arr[4] =>specific
arr[5] =>explode
arr[6] =>method,
arr[7] =>use
arr[8] =>instead
arr[9] =>javascript
arr[10] =>native
```

Comment: You are getting a String back so you need to convert that yourself.. It is not an Object or Array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use eval(). In order to split the file you have to change it's content little bit.

Txt file should look like this (see the quotes and some kind of delimeter - comma in this case):

```
arr[0] => "There",
arr[1] => "is",
arr[2] => "no",
arr[3] => "jQuery",
arr[4] => "specific",
arr[5] => "explode",
arr[6] => "method",
arr[7] => "use",
arr[8] => "instead",
arr[9] => "javascript",
arr[10] => "native",
```

See the [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/j3Luk/) (check the browser's console for output).